# How we can test login functionality, with different credentials at same time using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I wanna test login functionality of a website using JMeter. I wanna test it using multiple credentials at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Record your login flow using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for details.
2. Perform correlation of any dynamic parameters using [JMeter Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
3. Perform parameterisation of credentials using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
4. Adjust [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings and set the desired number of virtual users, ramp-up period and iterations count and/or test duration.
5. If you want all your login requests to happen at exactly the same moment put [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of this request and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to the desired value.

Comment: Firstly I recorded login process using BlazeMeter. After that I imported the .jmx file to Jmeter. Then I added a CSV data config.On login page csv request I changed the username and password values into variables and add these variables to csv config with csv file path.After that I added the listeners. But dont know why the file is not getting read.
Please suggest i8f missing something.

Answer (score 0):

**Login using multiple credentials to a web site with the help of Jmeter.**
1. Firstly record your script using Blazemeter.
2.Export .jmx file and the import it file to Jmeter.
3.Click on your login script. Then go to the username and password available on HTTP request.(If your website is not using CSRF tokens.)To perform this you have to disable this security.
4. Set your variables names like ${username} and ${password}.
5. Add a CSV Data Config  and add two comma separated variables.like username,password.This CSV data config read the data from CSV file, where we have two columns.one is for username and another  is for password.
6. Set the values in thread group, the number of times you want to run the  loop.
7.Run Test.